# How to convert structure of object to another structure? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this structure of JS object:

```
 const obj1 = {
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "type": "app"
        },
        {
          "name": "test2",
          "type": "app"
        },
        {
          "name": "test1",
          "type": "app2"
        },
        {
          "name": "test3",
          "type": "app2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need to finaly get this: 
Result:

```
 const obj1 = {
      app: {groups: [{name: 'test'},{name: 'test2'}]},
      app2: {groups: [{name: 'test1'},{name: 'test3'}]},
    }
```

May be ES6+ aproach or older

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to just iterating through `obj1.groups` building up a new output object:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "groups": [
    { "name": "test", "type": "app" },
    { "name": "test2", "type": "app" },
    { "name": "test1", "type": "app2" },
    { "name": "test3", "type": "app2" }
  ]
};

const out = {};
for (let group of obj1.groups) {
  out[group.type] = out[group.type] || { groups: [] };
  out[group.type].groups.push({ name: group.name });
}

console.log(out);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to wrap this up into a single expression:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "groups": [
    { "name": "test", "type": "app" },
    { "name": "test2", "type": "app" },
    { "name": "test1", "type": "app2" },
    { "name": "test3", "type": "app2" }
  ]
};

const out = obj1.groups.reduce((out, group) => {
  out[group.type] = out[group.type] || { groups: [] };
  out[group.type].groups.push({ name: group.name });
  return out;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: What is so great about using `reduce` here if you just mutate `out`? If you had written it with a plain `for … of` loop, the code would even have been shorter.

Comment: @Bergi Personally I find it easier to read as a `reduce`. You’re right though, a `for ... of` would work just as well here with minimal changes

Answer (score -1):

You can do it succinctly using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const obj1 = {
  "groups": [{ "name": "test", "type": "app" }, { "name": "test2", "type": "app" }, { "name": "test1", "type": "app2" }, { "name": "test3", "type": "app2" }]
};

const result = obj1.groups.reduce((obj, { name, type }) => {
  return (obj[type].groups.push({ name }), obj);
}, { app: { groups: [] }, app2: { groups: [] } });

console.log(result);
```

Or using the spread operator:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "groups": [{ "name": "test", "type": "app" }, { "name": "test2", "type": "app" }, { "name": "test1", "type": "app2" }, { "name": "test3", "type": "app2" }]
};

const result = obj1.groups.reduce((o, { name, type }) =>
  ({ ...o, [type]: { groups: [...((o[type] || {}).groups || []), { name }] } }), {});

console.log(result);
```